# Backdating a map from 1.7.x to 1.6.x

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have seen some megabuilds on PMC and would like to use it in a 1.6.x server however the map in question is a 1.7.x world. The question is what are the blocks that can potentially dissapear if i backdate the map? I can understand that moving out of the already generated region would cause shear cliffs as world gen code have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem you have is that from 1.6 to 1.7 was a big update. It was the update "*that changed the world*" and it was very big. Especially it got new biomes (11 are new, but have not really a impact on the buildings only on the ambiance) and the world generator changed alot. That means you could lose many blocks. I make you a little list here **only from the blocks** that could change the appearance from your buildings:

- Wood Varieties (Acacia Wood, Acacia and Dark Oak Wood Slabs, and
  more)
- Saplings (new trees)
- Leaves (new trees)
- Packed Ice
- Podzol
- Grassless Dirt
- Red Sand
- Flowers (Allium, Azure Bluet, and more | also the two blocks tall aswell the two block tall grass)
- Minecart with Command Block
- Stained Glass (all colours)

You should not have any problems uploading the map on your server (besides that the blocks are gone) and you also should be able to play it. And as you said there may will be the ugly cliffs.

Anyway, if your buildings have such blocks you should change them to similar blocks. Two tools that you could use are [WorldEdit](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/worldedit/) or [VoxelSniper](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/voxelsniper/). Both are very great tools. WorldEdit is easier to use. With VoxelSniper it will be faster. Keep in mind that both plugins are for bukkit servers (WorldEdit is also for singleplayer available).

I do not want to list all changes, but you can read them [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/The_Update_that_Changed_the_World). You also find the generator changes in there!

Comment: also the IDs will be different; in 1.7 they are fixed per world rather than fixed so mods can coexist without needing to coordinate IDs

Answer (score 1):

The changes are as follows

**New blocks!**
Two new types of wood.
Stained glass! With both blocks and panes.
Packed ice, red sand, podzol.
Lots of new flowers, including double-tall versions of current plants.
Portals can be bigger sizes!

These wood blocks are - Dark Oak - Acacia - and of course the planks and leaves for these. and what wasn't mentioned was the hardened clay with all of its colour types.

**New world generation!**
Double the amount of biomes, with new trees/flowers/blocks.
New “Amplified” world option.
Less ocean, more awesome.

Also worth noting is maps in frames will not work the same when backdating if this was used in the mega build

If the builds use these items they will simply not appear when you downgrade but what you could do is go into single player use a world edit utility and convert the blocks yourself to something similar

**EDIT**
*Also to note is that any unloaded chunks from the map will end up have ugly world boarders as the world gen changed drastically causing this issue.*